# php gettext returns msgid string

Tags: php, gettext

I'm following the tutorial [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/localizing-php-applications-1/), php is outputting the msgid instead of the msgstr. Here is what I have...

`extension=php_gettext.dll` uncommented in `php.ini` (this was already uncommented in xampp)

`php_gettext.dll` in `C:\xampp\php\ext` (this was already in xampp)

Directory structure `C:\xampp\htdocs\TestI18N\Locale\en_US\LC_MESSAGES` with created `messages.po` and `messages.mo` files in `LC_MESSAGES`.

A file called `test-locale.php` in `C:\xampp\htdocs\TestI18N` with the following

```
// I18N support information here
$language = "en_US";
putenv("LANG=" . $language); 
setlocale(LC_ALL, $language);

// Set the text domain as "messages"
$domain = "messages";
bindtextdomain($domain, "Locale"); 
bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, 'UTF-8');

textdomain($domain);

echo _("HELLO_WORLD");
```

My `messages.po` file

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: TestProject\n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2017-08-22 23:42+0300\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: 2017-08-22 23:53+0300\n"
"Last-Translator: \n"
"Language-Team: English\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"X-Generator: Poedit 2.0.3\n"
"X-Poedit-Basepath: .\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n != 1);\n"
"Language: en_US\n"
"X-Poedit-SourceCharset: UTF-8\n"

# Test token 1
msgid "HELLO_WORLD"
msgstr "Hello World!"

# Test token 2
msgid "TEST_TRANSLATION"
msgstr "Testing translation..."
```

The output is `HELLO_WORLD`. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I understand this question is old but in case it helps anyone else; the locale installed on my server was en_US.utf8 as opposed to just en_US.